# Blank screen when I release my app on app store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

when I archive my app and send the build to app store for review, the approver said me the app starts with blank screen. I tried to replicate the issue on simulator in different ways without success:

1. On xcode: product>scheme>Edit Schema I select Build Configuration "Release"
2. I changed the build settings in Xcode in the Debug configuration and temporarily turn up the optimisation level from (-O0) to (-O3 or -Os)

The app works fine on simulator without error, If I archive the application and I distribute it with ad-hoc option and I install manually on my device the app works fine too.

The only way to reproduce the problem is distribute the buid to app store and install it via test flight but i can't debug it.

Someone does anyone know what may be causing the problem? I think it could be a configuration problem.

Comment: I think what I would suggest is: run the test flight build with the console going and see if anything related pops up.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Sure you cannot run testflight build in debugger, but you can open Console and watch everything that comes from the runtime

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to try:

- Delete the app from your device before installing it from the Xcode debugger.
- Install the app using USB with the device in Airplane mode and WiFi turned off.

Comment: The problem is, the OP says the app behaves this same way in a test flight distribution. So it's not like we don't know how to reproduce the issue. The problem is finding out why. What could be different between a test flight distribution and an ad hoc distribution that could make this difference?

Comment: Your solutions does not work. If i install the app with usb and ad-hoc distribution it works fine. When i publish on store i Have the issue. The only way to test App Store distributed Version is to install it from test flight. If i follow this way I Have the issue. It is so strange

Comment: @xbomber360 Did you get the solution I am also facing same issue.Work fine on xcode but on TestFlight shows while screen

Answer (score 0):

For me it was even more strange. Local and Testflight builds worked just fine but AppStore review got a white screen and I had no success in reproducing it.

In my case it came down to that our CI system used a different (older) version of cocoapods than my local builds. This was when upgrading to cocoapods 1.14.3 which I think included quite a lot of changes to the ruby version handling etc. Maybe something there caused an issue since the pod version in the lock file was newer than what the CI used. I really do not know why it happened and  even less can I explain why the Testflight builds were fine but not the one that AppStore tested (it should be exactly the same build I presume).

Maybe there was something else on Apple's side but when I forced the CI to use the same cocoapods version as I had locally and resubmitted, the app passed the AppStore review again. Very strange. Anyway, adding the note here in case it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the problem.**

1. Open the project in Xcode.
2. Go to Build Phases.
3. In 'Bundle React Native code and images,' remove the code."